# How to fetch the resource ID of an virtual machine in azure using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure

how to get the resource ID of an VM in azure with using subscriptionID, vm name and resource group

Answer (score 0):

## We can use rest api to get resource id.

[Offical Doc: Virtual Machines - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/get#code-try-0)

[image]

[image]

**Test Code:**

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/b8***3f/resourceGroups/resourceGroupsname/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vmname?api-version=2020-06-01'
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer eyJ0eX****ZGw"}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
result=json.loads(r.text)

print('Resource ID= ' + result['id'])
```

**Result:**

[image]